# Извлечь данные координат из текста

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

> "geo":{"coordinates":{"lat":55.557551,"lng":37.554888}

Это маленький кусочек из большого текста, хочу вытащить данные по координатам при помощи регулярного выражения, но что-то получается не очень. 
Кто хорошо понимает в регулярках, подскажите как вытащить два числа. Спасибо!

Comment: а не проще ли поработать с JSON'ом?

Comment: Михаил, я бы с Вами согласился, но не совсем понятно как утащить JSON с html страницы, где очень много всего лишнего (включая другие куски JSON в разных местах). Страниц много и они меняются от раза к разу, я разбираю при помощи Jsoup, но вот с координатами затык вышел.

Comment: а можно пример ссылки?

Comment: Михаил, разбираю cian, все что нужно уже разобрал, остались только координаты. Вот для примера: https://www.cian.ru/sale/flat/193968155/

Comment: по похожим есть на виду запрос к АПИ...там есть вся инфа и координаты тоже.https://www.cian.ru/cian-api/site/v1/get-similar-offers-by-offer-id/?cianOfferId=193968155

Comment: Но мне не надо similar, я хочу скрапить по точным параметрам в запросе и так же сохранять ссылки на конкретные объявления в удобном для себя виде - табличном. Что-то не нашел инфо по cian-api, можете скинуть ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

> (?<=lat":)\d+.\d+|(?<=lng":)\d+.\d+

[пример](https://regex101.com/r/QOChN8/1)

Comment: Это работает отлично, спасибо!